# Issue when using security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri with server.ssl

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-boot, jwt, spring-cloud

We are developing a resource server based on Spring Boot+Cloud using OAuth2+JWT Token for security and using Cloud Foundry UAA as the authorization server.

For the verifier key, we used `security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri` property, so the resource server can dynamically pick up the public key from UAA at start up time. This was working all fine. When we tried to enable SSL in this resource server, we started to get `Cannot convert access token to JSON` error. When I debugged the code, it looked like it wasn't picking up the correct key to verify the signature. After spending some time, I figured out that it works if `key-value` is used instead of `key-uri`, but in that case you need to configure the key statically. It seems like a bug, but I am not 100% sure.

Is there a way to get the SSL working when still using `key-uri` for JWT? Or would you recommend a better and different approach to this?

Comment: The JWT verifier key is completely orthogonal to SSL in the container, so I don't think there can be any connection. You might need to provide more information, e.g. a link to a sample project.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I believe there was a separate certificate related issue that prevented the resource server to pull the public key. I guess we missed it in the logs or it didn't show up. It seemed to be resolved now. Thank you very much!